# Driver PsLookupProcessByProcessId error code 0xc000000b

Tags: c, windows, driver

I'm pretty new to driver programming. I have driver code which uses PsLookupProcessByProcessId routine. I'm trying to use Direct I/O. I'm sending PID from user mode using DWORD variable and read it into buf. Here is the snippet that produces the error code in IRP_MJ_WRITE MajorFunction:

```
PVOID buf=MmGetSystemAddressForMdlSafe(irp->MdlAddress,NormalPagePriority);
PEPROCESS Process = NULL;
DbgPrint("Process ID: %d",*(PHANDLE)buffer);

if(!NT_SUCCESS(status=PsLookupProcessByProcessId(*(PHANDLE)buf,&Process)))
        {
            DbgPrint("Error: (%#x)",status);
        }
```

The error code is 0xc000000b. When a PID is printed out, its printed correctly. I don't know why this error code is returned. According to http://doxygen.reactos.org/d3/d93/ntstatus_8h_a27310062c4edd9cc932e5607884904ae.html#a27310062c4edd9cc932e5607884904ae this error code should be rather returned from PsLookupProcessThreadByCid(). In function PsLookupProcessByProcessId I don't see any instructions that could return that error http://doxygen.reactos.org/d2/d9f/ntoskrnl_2ps_2process_8c_a85b05806391e5e2647dfdaea64b5b7a4.html#a85b05806391e5e2647dfdaea64b5b7a4. I don't know what the real problem is and I'm stuck. Please help me. I'm developing on windows 7 x64 free build environment.

Comment: Thank you very much, but the link is broken. I can't download the tool.

Comment: The documentation you link to is for ReactOS, not for Windows.

Comment: There are two obvious problems with that code snippet: you're printing the value of `*buffer` but passing the value of `*buf` to PsLookupProcessByProcessId, and you're passing an eight-byte value to DbgPrint but using a 4-byte specifier.  At a guess, the problem is that the user-mode program is passing a 4-byte process ID so the upper four bytes of the 8-byte ID you're passing are random junk.

Comment: @EvanCarslake: that link looks very suspicious to me.  In any case, in this context the problem is almost certainly with the OPs code.

Comment: @HarryJohnston yeah, was not suggesting to download that, it was just some reading. I don't have a lot of doubt that that is a true OS error specific to the users fine settings.

Comment: @Evan: that's a boilerplate page, machine generated.  If the text has any genuine relevance to this particular error, it's only by coincidence.  The problem is unlikely to be anything to do with the user's machine, since I don't see any legitimate search results suggesting that anyone is getting that particular error because of problems with their install.  (All I can see are boilerplate pages hawking snake oil and a few questions from driver developers.)

Comment: Yes, these links are reactOs. It was late night when i was looking for solution:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem:

> *(PHANDLE)buf

You're declaring `buf` to be a pointer to a `HANDLE` (8 bytes).  But you said the user code passes the process ID as a `DWORD` (4 bytes).

Try

> (HANDLE)(*(PDWORD)buf)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Harry Johnston's solution did the job ! Now it works fine.